# Show ListPlot markers only if criterion is met

Tags: plotting

I have a list (imported from csv file) of the form

```
data = {{1, "26/06/2006 15:00", 3, 0}, {2, "26/06/2006 15:05", 8, 0}, 
        {3, "26/06/2006 15:10", 9, 0}, {4, "26/06/2006 15:15", 8.5, 0},
        {5, "26/06/2006 15:20", 7, 0}, {6, "26/06/2006 15:25", 6, 1},
        {7, "26/06/2006 15:30", 3, 0}}
```

I want to plot the third and forth columns, where the third, the sample value, is joined, the forth, a flag, is not.

I only want to have a marker for the second option if it's value is 1 (not zero more generally). 
I have tried a couple of options that don't quite work.

```
ListPlot[{data[[;;, 3]], data[[;;, 4]]*10}, 
  Joined -> {True, False}, Filling -> Axis]
```

Ideally I don't want the first set with `Filling`, but I couldn't get it to use different arguments for both with

```
Filling -> {None, Axis}
```

I also don't want the 0 markers to show.

Effectively my 0/1 are just flags, I'll manually set a multiple for this to show nicely on the plot.

I tried to use `Select`, however this created a new list of just the 1 flags.

My actual dataset is many hundreds of thousands of lines, this is just a small example.

I have also tried making two separate plots, restricting the `PlotRange` and using `Show`, but as I need 0 in the first plot this didn't work. I could solve the filling problem this way.

EDIT: Error in the sample data, the first column should have indicated the x-value/ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Epilog` for that. Say, you have a data and you want to put markers only if the third element is 3 or 4.

```
data = {#, RandomReal[], RandomInteger[5]} & /@ Range[50];

c3 = Blue; s3 = Select[data, #[[3]] == 3 &][[All, {1, 2}]];
c4 = Red;  s4 = Select[data, #[[3]] == 4 &][[All, {1, 2}]];

ListLinePlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]], Epilog -> {PointSize[Large],
                                 c3, Point[s3], c4, Point[s4]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work for you.

```
data = 
   ({1, "26/06/2006 15:00", 3, 0},
    {1, "26/06/2006 15:05", 8, 0},
    {1, "26/06/2006 15:10", 9, 1},
    {1, "26/06/2006 15:15", 8.5, 0},
    {1, "26/06/2006 15:20", 7, 0},
    {1, "26/06/2006 15:25", 6, 1},
    {1, "26/06/2006 15:30", 3, 0}};

plotData = 
  With[{k = 10, pattern = {_, _, u_, v_}}, 
    Transpose[data /. {pattern /; v > 0 :> {u, 10 v}, pattern :> {u, Null}}]]
```

> `{{3, 8, 9, 8.5, 7, 6, 3}, {Null, Null, 10, Null, Null, 10, Null}}`

```
ListPlot[plotData,
  Joined -> {True, False},
  Filling -> 2 -> Axis,
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

This may be faster when there a lot of data points.

```
With[{k = 10},
  helper[{_, _, u_, v_ /; v > 0}] := {u, 10 v};
  helper[{_, _, u_, v_}] := {u, Null};
  plotData = Transpose[helper /@ data]]
```

Also you might consider automatically placing the markers on the plot.

```
helper[{_, _, u_, v_ /; v > 0}] := {u, u}
helper[{_, _, u_, v_}] := {u, Null}
plotData = Transpose[helper /@ data];

ListPlot[plotData,
  Joined -> {True, False},
  Filling -> 2 -> Axis,
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image: alt_plot]

Answer (score 1):

I set one more flag just to make the data more interesting.

```
data = {{1, "26/06/2006 15:00", 3, 1}, {1, "26/06/2006 15:05", 8, 0}, 
        {1, "26/06/2006 15:10", 9, 0}, {1, "26/06/2006 15:15", 8.5, 0}, 
        {1, "26/06/2006 15:20", 7, 0}, {1, "26/06/2006 15:25", 6, 1}, 
        {1, "26/06/2006 15:30", 3, 0}};
vals = data[[All, 3 ;; 4]] /. {___, _?(# == 0. &), ___} :> Sequence[];
ListPlot[vals[[All, 1]], Joined -> True, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Really just because I leak `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
data = {{1, "26/06/2006 15:00", 3, 0}, {1, "26/06/2006 15:05", 8, 
    0}, {1, "26/06/2006 15:10", 9, 1}, {1, "26/06/2006 15:15", 8.5, 
    0}, {1, "26/06/2006 15:20", 7, 0}, {1, "26/06/2006 15:25", 6, 
    1}, {1, "26/06/2006 15:30", 3, 0}};
{lp, p} = 
  Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[{#2[[1]], #1[[1]]}, #1[[2]]] &, 
    data[[All, {3, 4}]]], 1, #2 &];
ListPlot[lp, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[p[[1]]]}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

or using Sumit's data:

```
test = data = {#, RandomReal[], RandomInteger[5]} & /@ Range[50];
{tlp, tp} = Reap[Sow[{#1, #2}, #3] & @@@ test, 3 | 4, #2 &];
ListPlot[tlp, Joined -> True, 
 Epilog -> 
  MapThread[{#2, PointSize[0.02], Point[#1]} &, {tp, {Red, Blue}}]]
```

[image]